# Python reg exp - match number

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So I have this code that extract the integer from a string of the form: `Dir.<int>`

```
   def MatchDir(s):
      RegExp = re.compile('Dir.([0-9]+)')
      result = RegExp.match(s)
      try:
          return int(result.group(1))
      except:
          return None
```

problem is that it also matches strings such as `Dir.123_test` which is not desired.

How to resolve this to match only strings of the from `Dir.<int>` (no char is acceptable before or after this specific form)

Comment: `\b` or `$` depending on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of string:

```
RegExp = re.compile('^Dir.([0-9]+)$')
```

This won't allow anything other than `Dir.` and a number